# Module version when importing ES2015 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's suppose I have two ES2015 modules in the same folder:

```
//moduleone-1.5.0.js
export function temp() {
   console.log("Hi");
}

//moduletwo-2.0.0.js
import {temp} from './moduleone';//LINE X
temp();
```

Should I use `'./moduleone'` or `'./moduleone-1.5.0'` at LINE X? I need to understand how it must work according to specs.

Comment: Have you tried both?

Comment: @JonasWilms in node.js only './moduleone-1.5.0' works

Comment: npm has nothing to do with ES6 modules.

Comment: The specification does not impose any rules on the module identifier and how it is resolved. How that works depends on the module loader which is not part of the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "module version". You got two different modules, one named `moduleone-1.5.0` and one named `moduletwo-2.0.0`, those are the names you have to use for importing.

As you said you are using NodeJS (npm), you should actually install those modules by adding it to the `package.json`:

```
 { 
  "dependencies" :  {
    "moduleone" : "1.5.0"
  }
}
```

then you can `import from "moduleone";` and change the versions in the package spec as needed.

Comment: Depends on the module loader that you are using. It might indeed resolve `moduleone` to the current version of that module.

Comment: @bergi all the ones I know don't do that

Comment: @pavel_k the browser support is still not good, and in most cases I'd recommend bundling all modules to one js file to be served to the client.

Comment: @Pavel_K: Browsers likely treat module identifiers as file paths.